# How to get test method (or name) in JUnit 5 test class constructor?

Tags: java, junit5

I'm writing a very simple tests in JUnit 5 and wonder if it is at all possible to get the name or reference to the test method being executed in the constructor of the test class. I'm using a default approach of a separate test case instance per test method, so technically it should be possible. I was toying with `TestInfo` interface, but that one injected into constructor does not bear method context. Is there a different way of achieving this?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the constructor which require the test methods name you are going to call? The `@BeforeEach` method will get the correct `TestInfo.getTestMethod()` value.

Comment: I'm code golfing a bit for fun. I wanted test object field initializers to work based on the data from test method annotations, hence I wanted to get the method in the constructor.